Point of scientific-psychology tag
I'm not sure what's the point of the scientific-psychology tag. Almost anything qualifies, except the pseudo-scientific psychology?

I have not heard of the concept, but two of our high-rep users seem to have used it deliberately. Alex Stone added the tag to his question after it was suggested by Christian Hummeluhr.

I agree that with our current focus on scientifically based questions and answers it seems a bit of a deceptive tag.

There's a related discussion going on here https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2292/community-answer-for-questions-on-freudian-psychology?noredirect=1#comment5385_2292

I think the tag could be removed.
I agree the site is largely devoted to scientific questions about psychology, and therefore the tag does not differentiate questions.

As the tag still exists, I take it that, even though it could be confusing, this is not to be deleted? No meta description has been provided even though it was created somewhen between 2015 and 2018

It only applies to 5 questions. I think it could be safely removed.

I think I agree

@ChrisRogers Moderators can't remove a tag except by editing the same as anyone else. The SE term for removing a tag by editing it out of all the questions using it is "burnination": https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burninate-system If there's a large number of posts with a tag, the usual process is to do them just a few at a time.

I've removed this tag from the 5 questions that used it. It will be cleaned up/removed entirely from the system the next time the tag maintenance script runs.
